# how to draw each node by networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I know there's a function, `nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=200, node_color='#00b4d9')` can draw all nodes in the network. However, each of my node have a different color,dataset and code like that,

```
df_name = ['A','B','C','D','E']
val_idx = [1,2,3,4,5]
pred_pca_spec = [1,2,0,1,4]

#Note! below is rgb color value of each sample
val_rgb = [[130,  89,  34],[170, 133,  75],[126,  85,  17],[120,  81,  37],[162, 126,  65]]  

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('no.1')
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
for i in range(0, len(df_name)):
    if pred_pca_spec[i] == 1:      
        G.add_edge('no.1', int(val_idx[i])) # I want to set color in this line at same time,like
######G.add_edge('no.1', node_value = int(val_idx[i]), node_color = '#%02x%02x%02x' % tuple(val_rgb[i]))#####
nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.show()
```

Is there some function can achieve it?
**Note**!Because dataset are dyes textile samples so I must show true color of them, only can use the rgb color space, **not**

> colors = ["r", "g", "b", "y", "w"]

please!

Comment: You can simply supply a list of colors (same length as number of nodes) and then each node has a different color in your plot

Comment: @Sparky05 I have a list of color but I have to pick some color which label is '1'

Comment: Can you add these details to your question? And maybe supply a minimal example including desired output? A handful of nodes is sufficient.

Comment: @Sparky05 hi, thanks for your reply I add the dataet in detail, please have a check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure, what exactly your problem is or where you struggle or why you want to add the color within the for loop.
However, I hope the following code solves your problem.
Using [Color using RGB value in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797527/color-using-rgb-value-in-matplotlib) I casted your RGB to values between 0 and 1.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

df_name = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
val_idx = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
pred_pca_spec = [1, 2, 0, 1, 4]
val_rgb = [[130, 89, 34],
           [170, 133, 75],
           [126, 85, 17],
           [120, 81, 37],
           [162, 126, 65], ]

val_rgb = [(r / 255, g / 255, b / 255) for r, g, b in val_rgb]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('no.1')
G.nodes['no.1']["color"] = tuple(val_rgb[0])  # or whatever color you like
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
for i in range(0, len(df_name)):
    if pred_pca_spec[i] == 1:
        node = int(val_idx[i])
        G.add_edge('no.1', node)
        G.nodes[node]["color"] = val_rgb[i]

nx.draw_networkx(G, node_color=[G.nodes[node]["color"] for node in G])
plt.show()
```

Result

[image]

Comment: I dont want use ["r", "g", "b", "y", "w"] because my samples are dyes textile, it must show the true color, so how could change it?

Comment: In your example, you haven't included any color information. You can replace them with any color specifications, but you need to already have the information of the node's color, e.g. in an array (as I did), or data frame, or file.